# iOS 13 Dark Mode in React Native with Tab Bar and Navigation Bar

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-navigation, navigationbar

I am currently trying to have a set up with a bottom tab bar, and inside the tabs, each a navigation stack with navigation bar. I use the following code based on the react navigation [sample app](https://github.com/react-navigation/theme-example/blob/master/App.tsx) (just minor edits on the imports, as some things were moved).

Unfortunately, only the tab bar is displayed in the dark mode color on iOS 13 simulator (dark grey), the navigation bar is white. How can I get it to display as well in the dark mode color?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import {
  createAppContainer,
  Themed,
} from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { AppearanceProvider, useColorScheme } from 'react-native-appearance';

function A() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Themed.Text>B</Themed.Text>
    </View>
  );
}

A.navigationOptions = { title: 'Hello from A' };

function B() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Themed.Text>B</Themed.Text>
    </View>
  );
}

B.navigationOptions = { title: 'Hello from B!!!!' };

let StackA = createStackNavigator({ A });
let StackB = createStackNavigator({ B });
let Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({ StackA, StackB });
let Navigation = createAppContainer(Tabs);

export default function App() {
  let theme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <AppearanceProvider>
      <Navigation theme={theme} />
    </AppearanceProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/themes.html#built-in-themes-inside-navigationoptions

Use `theme` within `navigationOptions`.

To integrate this with your code:

```js
// ...
const stackDefaultNavigationOptions = ({ theme }) => { 
  // theme will be either 'light' or 'dark',
  // choose however you want to retrieve the colors for that

  // using ternary here as just a simple example,
  // but you could instead have a theme object with the keys light and dark
  return {
    title: 'Home',
    headerTintColor: theme === 'light' ? 'black' : 'white',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: theme === 'light' ? 'white' : 'black' },    
  }
}

const StackA = createStack({ A }, { defaultNavigationOptions: stackDefaultNavigationOptions })
const StackB = createStack({ B }, { defaultNavigationOptions: stackDefaultNavigationOptions })

// ...

export default function App() {
  let theme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <AppearanceProvider>
        <Navigation theme={theme} />
    </AppearanceProvider>
  )
}

// ...
```

Comment: How does that work together with the AppearanceProvider and the {theme} of it? This is passed into the <Navigation theme={theme}> and also used by the tab bar automatically? If I use screenProps in the code above, it tells me that the currenttheme would be undefined. Can you maybe provide an example based on the code above?

Comment: I have provided an example, hopefully that will make it more clear. I also read more and realized that `screenProps` isn't necessary, you can pass `theme` directly into `navigationOptions`/`defaultNavigationOptions`. You will have to manually set the colors for light and dark mode for the stack headers.

Answer (score 0):

Use React navigation themes built-in plugin. If you use Expo, on iOS 13+ you can add the [Appearance](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/appearance/) to detect preferred color scheme.

```
const Navigation = createAppContainer(RootStack);
export default () => <Navigation theme="light" />;
```

Check the docs. [RN Themes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/themes.html)

Alternatively, you can use npm package [react-native-dark-mode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dark-mode)